# Training Estimators less than one epoch using dataset API?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to train a model on a large dataset. I would like to run the evaluation step multiple times before one epoch of training has been completed. Looking at the implementation of Dataset API with Estimators it looks like every time I restart the training after the evaluation step, Estimator creates a fresh dataset from scratch and the training never completes for the full data.

I have written an input function very similar to one provided on the tensorflow website.

```
def train_input_fn(features, labels, batch_size):
    """An input function for training"""
    # Convert the inputs to a Dataset.
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(features), 
    labels))

    # Shuffle, repeat, and batch the examples.
    dataset = dataset.repeat(1).batch(batch_size)

    # Return the read end of the pipeline.
    return dataset
```

I then use the tf.estimator.Estimator.train to call my input function. I call the above input function with the following method.

```
classifier.train(input_fn=lambda: train_input_fn, 
steps=n_steps)
```

where n_steps in number less than the total step taken to complete one epoch.

I then call an evaluation function like this.

```
classifier.evaluate(input_fn=lambda: eval_input_fn())
```

I want the run both the step in a loop.
Every time the loop reaches training, It initialization the dataset in the train_input_fn. This applies the training only in first n_steps of training data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to evaluate multiple times during training, you can check [InMemoryEvaluatorHook](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.9/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/estimator/InMemoryEvaluatorHook).

You can probably refer [this discussion](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13895#issuecomment-374796583) about [train_and_evaluate](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/train_and_evaluate) and InMemoryEvaluatorHook for more details on how to better use them.